# Improve Function performance in Postgresql

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, function

Following function is creating a temp table and then populating data in it.

That temp table is supposed to be displayed  on click of a button on a website.

Steps I tried to improve performance:
1. Modified postgresql.conf file.
2. Added index in temp table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lastonemonth()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
  query1 text;
  query2 text;
  var_loop1 RECORD;
  dealerName text;
  cur_minus_2_month text; 
  var_sum_of_quantity numeric;
  var_net_value numeric;
  var_average_price_nsr numeric; 
  BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LOM CASCADE';
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE LOM ( dealer_name text PRIMARY KEY , sum_of_quantity numeric, net_value numeric, average_price_nsr numeric)';
  EXECUTE 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dealer_name_idx ON LOM (dealer_name)';

  query1:= 'SELECT DISTINCT dealer FROM customernotorderdb_temp WHERE month IN ( to_char( now() - interval ''2 month'', ''YYYYMM'') , to_char( now() - interval ''3 month'', ''YYYYMM''))EXCEPT SELECT DISTINCT dealer FROM customernotorderdb_temp WHERE month IN ( to_char( now() - interval ''1 month'', ''YYYYMM''), to_char(now(), ''YYYYMM'') )';
  FOR var_loop1 IN EXECUTE (query1)
  LOOP
      dealerName:= var_loop1.dealer;
      INSERT INTO LOM(dealer_name) VALUES(dealerName);
      EXECUTE 'SELECT month FROM customernotorderdb_temp WHERE dealer LIKE ''%'||dealerName||'%'' AND month IN(to_char( now() - interval ''2 month'', ''YYYYMM''))' INTO cur_minus_2_month;

      --RAISE NOTICE 'cur_minus_2_month( % )', cur_minus_2_month;
      IF cur_minus_2_month IS NOT NULL 
      THEN
          EXECUTE 'SELECT SUM(saleqtypermt) FROM customernotorderdb_temp WHERE dealer LIKE ''%'||dealerName||'%'' AND month IN (to_char( now() - interval ''2 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''3 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''4 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''5 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''6 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''7 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() -interval ''8 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''9 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''10 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''11 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''12 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''13 month'', ''YYYYMM''))' INTO var_sum_of_quantity;
          EXECUTE 'SELECT SUM(basic_value-rate_diff) FROM customernotorderdb_temp WHERE dealer LIKE ''%'||dealerName||'%'' AND month IN (to_char( now() - interval ''2 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''3 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''4 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''5 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''6 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''7 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() -interval ''8 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''9 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''10 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''11 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''12 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''13 month'', ''YYYYMM''))' INTO var_net_value;
          EXECUTE 'SELECT SUM(avgpricensr) FROM customernotorderdb_temp WHERE dealer LIKE ''%'||dealerName||'%'' AND month IN (to_char( now() - interval ''2 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''3 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''4 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''5 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''6 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''7 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() -interval ''8 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''9 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''10 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''11 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''12 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''13 month'', ''YYYYMM''))' INTO var_average_price_nsr;
          --RAISE NOTICE 'A [ %   % ]', dealername,var_net_value;
          UPDATE LOM SET sum_of_quantity=var_sum_of_quantity,
                         net_value=var_net_value,
                         average_price_nsr=var_average_price_nsr 
          WHERE dealer_name=var_loop1.dealer;

      ELSE
          EXECUTE 'SELECT SUM(saleqtypermt) FROM customernotorderdb_temp WHERE dealer LIKE ''%'||dealerName||'%'' AND month IN (to_char( now() - interval ''3 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''4 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''5 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''6 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''7 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() -interval ''8 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''9 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''10 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''11 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''12 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''13 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''14 month'', ''YYYYMM''))' INTO var_sum_of_quantity;
          EXECUTE 'SELECT SUM(basic_value-rate_diff) FROM customernotorderdb_temp WHERE dealer LIKE ''%'||dealerName||'%'' AND month IN (to_char( now() - interval ''3 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''4 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''5 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''6 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''7 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() -interval ''8 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''9 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''10 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''11 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''12 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''13 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''14 month'', ''YYYYMM''))' INTO var_net_value;
          EXECUTE 'SELECT SUM(avgpricensr) FROM customernotorderdb_temp WHERE dealer LIKE ''%'||dealerName||'%'' AND month IN (to_char( now() - interval ''3 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''4 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''5 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''6 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''7 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() -interval ''8 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''9 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''10 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''11 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''12 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''13 month'', ''YYYYMM''),to_char( now() - interval ''14 month'', ''YYYYMM''))' INTO var_average_price_nsr;
          --RAISE NOTICE 'B [ %  % ]', dealername,var_net_value;
          UPDATE LOM SET sum_of_quantity=var_sum_of_quantity,net_value=var_net_value,average_price_nsr=var_average_price_nsr WHERE dealer_name=var_loop1.dealer;
      END IF;         
 END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: you didn't run ANALYZE over the table. Newer drop temp table, truncate it instead. Then you can use static SQL.

Comment: You don't need a function; you don't need a loop, you don't need plpgsql. The function effectively does `INSERT INTO LOM(...) SELECT dealer_name, SUM(xxx0), ... FROM customernotorderdb_temp GROUP BY dealer_name` (plus some other aggregations and selections)

Comment: After above mentioned suggestions following is the code:

Comment: `WHERE dealer LIKE ''%'||dealerName||'%''` why do you use wildcards here? you got the dealername from exacty the same table!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you're storing months as strings and manually doing date comparisons with strings. That'll slow it down. Could you do it with Postgres date types or integers instead?

For other things, I can't really tell without knowing your database layout and statistics, but here's the basic method for optimizing queries:

1. Open a new connection using psql or something.
2. `set enable_seqscan = off`, which disables seq scan in the query planner (unless completely necessary) only for this session.
3. Run `EXPLAIN` before your queries to see which ones are being forced to scan large tables. Add indexes if you see any `SEQ SCAN`s.

Comment: "EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT lastonemonth();st=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=16959.720..16959.721 rows=1 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 16959.734 ms"

Comment: Many thanks, Now  efficiency of code is EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT lastonemonth();"Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=2783.845..2783.845 rows=1 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 2783.859 ms"

Comment: Nice. What did you change? You didn't post the query plan that EXPLAIN produced.

Comment: 1. remove wild character % 2. Added explicit index. 3. Under the if block  merged three execute statement into one 4. Modified postgresql.conf  file settings 5.Removed 'CREATE' and 'DROP' statements from the function 6. Removed one variable in deceleration section